# Como forçar a leitura de todos os resultados existentes no REST em uma página?

Tags: php, mysql, array, rest, restful

```
foreach ($result as $indices) {

    // Aqui ele retorna 50 registros por conuslta
    echo $indices['Empreendimento'];

    // Provavelmente preciso de um loop da paginação aqui dentro
    // para falar para o foreach que enquanto houver paginação, que
    // ele continue buscando e listando os registros

}
```

Estou fazendo uma consulta em um servidor `REST` que me retorna 50 resultados por vez e faz paginação do restante dos registros provavelmente para melhorar o gerenciamento de tráfego e não sobrecarregar o servidor.

Eu quero retornar todos os registros numa só página e acho que posso fazer isso usando um `for` ou `foreach` para dizer a consulta que enquanto não terminar o carregamento de todos os registros, continua buscando entre as páginas e listado os registros, tudo numa só página.

Eu acho que a solução é ler esta paginação dentro do `foreach` com outro loop mas não sei aplicar. Caso queiram dar uma olhada na página, **[AQUI](http://new.pier36imoveis.com.br/vista/listar_imoveis.php)**

**Pergunta:** Como extrair todos os dados em uma só página percorrendo as paginações e trazendo os resultados?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Isso depende da aplicação que roda no servidor. Se a aplicação permitir que você passe um parametro para que mais registros apareçam por página aí você conseguirá fazer isso com uma requisição apenas.

Caso não exista essa possibilidade, você terá que iterar sobre cada página, onde cada página será uma requisição HTTP. O parametro **pagina** deve ser passado por POST para que você consiga obter o resultado de uma página, veja imagem abaixo:

[image: Parametro que deve ser passado para obter uma página]

Comment: A aplicação não permite que eu puxe mais registros então eu preciso usar a segunda opção que é iterar sob cada página mas não sei fazer isso !!! Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você já consegue iterar sobre a 1a pagina, certo?

Comment: Sim, a primeira página eu tenho os primeiros 50 registros mas preciso que todos os registros apareçam nela e é isso que não consigo fazer.

Comment: Mas isso vc nao vai conseguir fazer de uma vez só. Para resolver, você vai precisar passar um parametro pra sua requisicao HTTP. Este parametro vai via POST e se chama pagina. Experimente fazer um teste, passando o parametro pagina com valor 2 e veja o resultado.

Comment: Eu já fiz isso. Na própria imagem que você postou tem essa paginação. Mas eu preciso de todos os resultados em uma página só para pegar tudo isso e cadastrar no banco de dados.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, veja bem. Nao é possível ter todos os resutaldos numa pagina só, pois a aplicação te limita. O que vc deve fazer é um loop de acordo com o numero de paginas e, cada iteração desse loop, você deve fazer uma requisição HTTP para a página corrente e alimentar o seu banco de dados. Portanto, se sao 3 paginas, sao três iterações do loop. A restrição não está na sua aplicação, está na aplicação dos imoveis. Você, portanto, precisa se adequar a isso.

Comment: Não sei fazer essa iteração. Pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Veja se na response de sua requisição a API retorna um header com a quantidade total de páginas. Geralmente APIs REST retornam isso. Não vi seu código, então use o exemplo abaixo apenas para entender a lógica.

```
$primeiraRequisicao = $api->imoveis();
//Retorno da API para o total de páginas
$pages = $primeiraRequisicao->totalPages;
if($pages > 1)
    for($i = 2; $i <= $pages; $i++){
        //O parâmetro é o número da página
        $api->imoveis($i);
        //Junte os resultados da sua requisição
        //com a primeira requisição feita antes da iteração
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, se o servidor da API já tem um limite é para o tempo de resposta ser mais rapido.

Aconcelho a não fazer um foreach, apenas fazer a requisição de acordo com a demanda do usuario. O que pode ajudar no tempo de resposta do usuario do seu sistema.